# Separate ports for Strapi and React won't work under the same domain

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, openssl, strapi

The project was very OK when I worked locally under development. Because the ports of backend `1337` and frontend `3000` were manually changed by me. After we deployed the project to the cloud server, we made OpenSSL work for the frontend. It meant to make `nginx` redirect requests from port `80` to safe `443`, which expected to load the SSL certification. All is well until we tried to log in with our `1337` port to Strapi admin panel, which is part of a backend directory.
To be clear:

- backend runs on `1337`
- frontend runs on `5000`.

Both server processes run in pm2 in the background with no problem. nginx file seems to not have any syntax errors. But I can not reach any of the backend operations even through Postman.

What I expect it to do is: *run all requests started with `domain.com/api/` through `localhost:1337`. As it made happen with main directory, run through 'localhost:5000'*.  This is `nginx` config file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name sinavhukuk.com www.sinavhukuk.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/site80port.com.access.log;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name sinavhukuk.com www.sinavhukuk.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/sinavhukuk.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/sinavhukuk.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'XXXXXXXXXX';
        location /{
                proxy_pass    http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/main-dir-error.log debug;
        }
        location /api{
                proxy_pass    http://localhost:1337;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                error_log /var/log/nginx/admin-error.log debug;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/siteSSL.com.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/siteSSL.com.error.log;

}
```

Comment: Can you reach the frontend?

Comment: Yes frontend works as expected